# React native `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` promise will never be resolved/rejected when user selected 'never ask again' and disabled geolocation

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation

I'm using React native v0.56 and have issue on android...
Actually title of this topic almost complete except one thing
timeout property is not working
iOS is working, android never fires resolve/reject functions
What i need to do in this case? Report a bug in to react native? Or may be there is `hidden knowledge`?)
Help me, please(

Comment: please share your code of getting current location

Comment: There is an issue with rejection on Android : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/22843

Answer (score -2):

UPD 2020: navigator.geolocation DEPRECATED.
Use this library
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation

Comment: getCurrentPosition doesn't work with then... returns this error "Invariant Violation: Must provide a valid geo_success callback."